# How to keep last [integer] lines in file which contains specified <string>

Tags: java

Keeping lines with only the last [integer] lines specified in the file which contain the provided

Hi, I'm reading in a string array file line by line. An argument is passed in with to keep an integer (i.e., -k string, optional integer). I need to keep lines with only the last [integer] lines in the file which contain the provide . Thanks in advance.

if (arguments.equals("-k")) {

```
 //read all lines in file
 List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(filename));

 //keep phrase after -k
 List<String> toKeep = Arrays.asList((args[i + 1]));

 //New list string matchedLines sort file containing phrase -r
    List<String> matchedLines = lines.stream().sorted()
                                .filter(e -> 
                                (toRemove.stream().filter(d ->
                                e.contains(d)).count()) < 1)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

FILE = "1 the white and black fox\r 2 the bird is with the red and black";

String args[] = {"-k", "i", "1", inputFile.getPath()};

expected output: 
          2 the bird is with the red and black

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to keep the last `n` results *after* filtering for matches, you could reassign the variable and use Java 8 streams `skip` method:

```
// Collect list of strings that match -k
List<String> matchedLines = lines.parallelStream()
                    .sorted()
                    .filter(line -> toKeep.stream().anyMatch(line::contains))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

// Get only n matches
matchedLines = matchedLines.stream()
                    .skip(Math.max(0, matchedLines.size() - n))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This skips the first `matchedLines.size() - n` lines where `n` is the number of lines you want to return. If `n` is larger than the number of matched strings, e.g. `matchedLines.size() - n < 0`, it will return all of the items (by skipping 0).